# Interpolation polynomials

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Let $p_k$ be the polynomial of degree $\leq k$ such that $p_k(x_i)=y_i$ for $0\leq i \leq k$. Prove that $p_k=p_{k-1}$ if and only if $p_{k-1}(x_k)=y_k$.

I'm a first year PhD student and I encountered this problem in one of my courses. I feel like I intuitively understand the solution to this problem, but I am not sure how to prove it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V_k$ be the Vandermonde matrix of order $k + 1$ at the points $x_0,\ldots,x_k$. Then $V_k C_k = Y_k$, where $C_k$ is the vector of coefficients of $p_k$ and $Y_k = (y_0,\ldots,y_k)^T$. Assuming the points $x_0,\ldots,x_k$ are distinct, the matrix $V_k$ is invertible. Now, let $C_{k-1}$ be the coefficient vector for $p_{k-1}$ and let $Y_{k-1} = (y_0,\ldots,y_{k-1})^T$. If $p_{k-1}(x_k) = y_k$, then

$$
V_k
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
C_{k-1}\\
0\\
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
Y_{k-1}\\
y_k\\
\end{array}\right] = Y_k
$$

and by the invertibility of $V_k$

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
C_{k-1}\\
0\\
\end{array}\right] = C_k
$$

Thus, it follows that $p_{k-1} = p_{k}$. The other direction follows by the observation that $p_{k-1} = p_{k} \implies p_{k-1}(x_k) = p_k(x_k) = y_k$.